# Writing Custom Python Layer With Learnable Parameters in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I know that [this example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_python_layer.py#L31) is supposed to illustrate how to add trainable parameters in a [Python layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410) using the `add_blob()` method.

However, I am still unable to understand how this can be used to set the dimensions of the blob based on user defined parameters.

There is a better example here on how to write a Python layer [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py).
But here, the layer does not contain any trainable parameters.

Please explain how to write a custom Python layer with trainable parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "set dimensions of the blob". AFAIK, caffe sets the top blob size based on the bottom blob size and properties of the current layer; so, you don't need to set the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a parameters blob using `add_blob()`, you can `reshape` the added blob, either in `setup()` method (right when you add it), or in the layer's `reshape()` method.

Comment: Could you comment on how to let the layer have hyper-parameters that are user-defined in the train_val.prototxt file ? Also, are you required to make any changes in the caffe.proto or the header files when writing a custom Python layer?